# OpenbravoERP after login still it shwoing Loading

Tags: java, tomcat6, openbravo

In OpenbravoERP everything I am installed successfully. When I am trying to login it will goes to one loading page and nothing happen after that.When I'm checking tomcat logs in CATALINA.OUT ,no error is there. Next I checked OPENBRAVO.log ,then it showing smothing error. Please give me an answer ..... 
I'm

giving the openbravo.log here..

> roney@roney-Satellite-C850:/var/lib/tomcat6/logs$ tail -f openbravo3.log
>   2014-11-15 14:53:01,802 [Thread-6] INFO  org.openbravo.base.OBSchedulerInitializerListener - Quartz Scheduler successful shutdown.
>   2014-11-17 10:11:14,656 [main] INFO  org.openbravo.dal.core.DalLayerInitializer - Initializing in-memory model...
>   2014-11-17 10:11:14,699 [main] INFO  org.openbravo.base.model.ModelProvider - Building runtime model
>   2014-11-17 10:11:23,998 [main] INFO  org.openbravo.dal.core.DalLayerInitializer - Model read in-memory, generating mapping...
>   2014-11-17 10:11:34,501 [main] INFO  org.openbravo.dal.core.DalLayerInitializer - Dal layer initialized
>   2014-11-17 10:11:34,556 [main] INFO  org.openbravo.base.OBSchedulerInitializerListener - Quartz Initializer Servlet loaded, initializing Scheduler...
>   2014-11-17 10:11:34,623 [main] INFO  org.openbravo.base.OBSchedulerInitializerListener - Scheduler will start in 30 seconds.
>   2014-11-17 10:11:34,623 [main] INFO  org.openbravo.base.OBSchedulerInitializerListener - Storing the Quartz Scheduler Factory in the servlet context at key: org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.KEY
>   2014-11-17 10:11:34,623 [main] INFO  org.openbravo.base.OBSchedulerInitializerListener - Storing ConfigParameters and ConnectionProvider in Scheduler Context.
>   2014-11-17 10:11:34,633 [main] INFO  org.openbravo.base.OBSchedulerInitializerListener - Initalizing singleton instance of org.openbravo.scheduling.OBScheduler
>   2014-11-17 10:15:07,065 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR org.openbravo.scheduling.ProcessRequestData - SQL error in query:           UPDATE AD_Process_Request       SET Updatedby = ?, AD_User_ID = ?, Status = ?, Channel = ?,         Previous_Fire_Time = TO_TIMESTAMP(?, ?),        Next_Fire_Time = TO_TIMESTAMP(?, ?),        Scheduled_Finish = TO_TIMESTAMP(?, ?),          Ob_Context = ?          WHERE AD_Process_Request_ID = ?Exception:java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

2014-11-17 10:15:07,068 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR org.openbravo.scheduling.ProcessMonitor - @CODE=1830@ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

javax.servlet.ServletException: @CODE=1830@ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

```
at org.openbravo.scheduling.ProcessRequestData.update(ProcessRequestData.java:337)
at org.openbravo.scheduling.ProcessMonitor.triggerFired(ProcessMonitor.java:102)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyTriggerListenersFired(QuartzScheduler.java:1793)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.notifyListenersBeginning(JobRunShell.java:310)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:176)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
```

2014-11-17 10:16:49,008 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] ERROR org.openbravo.scheduling.ProcessRequestData - SQL error in query:           UPDATE AD_Process_Request       SET Updatedby = ?, AD_User_ID = ?, Status = ?, Channel = ?,         Previous_Fire_Time = TO_TIMESTAMP(?, ?),        Next_Fire_Time = TO_TIMESTAMP(?, ?),        Scheduled_Finish = TO_TIMESTAMP(?, ?),          Ob_Context = ?          WHERE AD_Process_Request_ID = ?Exception:java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

2014-11-17 10:16:49,009 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] ERROR org.openbravo.scheduling.ProcessMonitor - @CODE=1830@ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

javax.servlet.ServletException: @CODE=1830@ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

```
at org.openbravo.scheduling.ProcessRequestData.update(ProcessRequestData.java:337)
at org.openbravo.scheduling.ProcessMonitor.triggerFired(ProcessMonitor.java:102)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyTriggerListenersFired(QuartzScheduler.java:1793)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.notifyListenersBeginning(JobRunShell.java:310)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:176)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
```

Comment: there might me conflict in your `config` folder, replace it with working appdir `config` folder, or do `ant setup` and re-run the configuration setup.

Answer (score 1):

You might have copied openbravo.properties file from somewhere ?? or was not configured properly.

try this

```
Editing the Configuration files
  1. Move to the OpenbravoERP-3.0PR14Q3.3 directory in a command line terminal and run:
          ant setup
  2. Move to the OpenbravoERP-3.0PR14Q3.3/config directory.
      Access the graphical configuration wizard:
      Linux: make executable and run setup-properties-linux.bin
               If you face any segfaults running this tool, add --mode xwindow or --mode text as an argument.

      Windows: run setup-properties-windows.exe
      Configure the Openbravo.properties and log4j.lcf files using the configuration wizard.
```

and run `ant compile.complete.deploy` in openbravo directory

for full instructions you can visit [openbravo installation link](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Custom/Openbravo_Setup)

Comment: Thank you Mani Deep, Actually I resolved the problem. Problem is denied  permission to copy one js file in tomcat webapps. I given the permission, problem is resolved. Actually I'm using Ubuntu machine. Once again THANK YOU Mani Deep. I expect your help in future.